# Reapplying for a UK tourist visa after being refused once

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-employment

I am an Indian citizen (also holder of Schengen residence permit) got married recently and want to visit London for 5 days with my wife (Indian citizen) for our honeymoon.

I have been previously refused a visit visa by UK mission in Warsaw in March 2015. I am a self-employed freelancer (have no means of stable income) approx 500 euro per month. I have about 10,000 euros to show in my bank statement (business income).

I have genuine intention of returning back to India after the visit. What documents should I arrange to have a strong case on my side?

We wouldn't really worry much, even if they deny us a visa, but curious about the legal procedure involved.

Comment: A prior refusal, big change of circumstances... You should throw some of that EUR 10k at a decent solicitor and let them guide you through. Otherwise just read the guidance. There's no special legal procedure, just fill out the form for yourself and another for your wife (two applications).

Comment: Thank you Gayot. Do you know any decent solicitor or perhaps you are available for help :J

Comment: Heavens no, I don't do casework any more. Yuck! There's some great people, highly qualified at http://www.ilpa.org.uk/  About 200 to chose from.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate, and I believe I've found the dupe. Please flag if I'm incorreect, but we have a lot of similar questions on the site.  Closing now...